# Tail recursion, how do we eliminate the return statement?

Tags: c#, recursion, tail-recursion

Here is a tail recursive C# program that sums the squares of 1 through 10. It works, except for the last else  in `AddSquares2()`.  It does not work because C# seems to demand a return statement in every path in a method that returns a value. However, I shouldn't need a return statement in a tail recursive method such as this one. See the comment.

Is this just an idiosyncrasy of C#? Or is there a way to tell the compiler that I know what I'm doing and that I don't want every path to return a value?

Here is my program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Recursive
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int start = 1;
            int end = 10;
            int sum = 0;
            AddSquares(start, end, sum);
            sum = AddSquares2(start, end, sum);
        }

        private static int AddSquares2(int start, int end, int sum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"AddSquares2({start}, {end}, {sum})");
            if (start > end)
                return (sum);
            else
                //should not have to return anything here
                return(AddSquares2(start + 1, end, sum + start * start));
        }

        private static void AddSquares(int start, int end, int sum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"AddSquares({start}, {end}, {sum})");
            if (start > end)
                Console.WriteLine($"  The total sum is {sum}");
            else
                AddSquares(start + 1, end, sum + start * start);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
 AddSquares(1, 10, 0)
    AddSquares(2, 10, 1)
    AddSquares(3, 10, 5)
    AddSquares(4, 10, 14)
    AddSquares(5, 10, 30)
    AddSquares(6, 10, 55)
    AddSquares(7, 10, 91)
    AddSquares(8, 10, 140)
    AddSquares(9, 10, 204)
    AddSquares(10, 10, 285)
    AddSquares(11, 10, 385)
      The total sum is 385
    AddSquares2(1, 10, 0)
    AddSquares2(2, 10, 1)
    AddSquares2(3, 10, 5)
    AddSquares2(4, 10, 14)
    AddSquares2(5, 10, 30)
    AddSquares2(6, 10, 55)
    AddSquares2(7, 10, 91)
    AddSquares2(8, 10, 140)
    AddSquares2(9, 10, 204)
    AddSquares2(10, 10, 285)
    AddSquares2(11, 10, 385)
      The total sum is 385
```

Comment: How do you expect a function of type int not to return anything? In your if...else statements, the if statement is checked first. if it is true, it should return something else if it doesn't it also has to return something. May be you can return 0 or null.

Comment: Hrmm, so in any other language (functional or not), what do you do, what is the value that is returned by this else, what happens to the code execution, it just disappears?

Comment: Are you under the impression that the `return sum` in that function is going to magically bypass all the previous calls and return directly to `Main`?

Comment: The `else` still needs to return a value at some point when the stack unwinds after the recursion and execution hits that final closing brace in `AddSquares2`...remember, execution will continue after calling that method in the `else` block. You need to do something with the return value of the recursive call or it will never get sent to the caller.

Comment: Are you asking why you have to use the “return” keyword and can’t instead simply leave it out and and just have the call? You think the compiler should implicitly determine that you mean to have the result of the call returned since in this scenario a tail call optimization *can* be performed. That’s just not how C# was designed. Leaving out the return keyword here is just sort of like saying “ignore the results of the call and explicitly don’t return it”

Comment: In loose lancuages that allows return in only one of tha tail positions you'd get an undefined value as the result whenever the recursive step was used. Thus it works, but not as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Question is correct in its assertion that it shouldn't need to "return", but it depends on your meaning of "return". In a low-level sense, *if* a tail call is performed, then no "ret" instruction (some sort of standard stack cleanup type instruction) needs to be performed at this point, since the tail call will make the actual execution behave equivalent to a simple loop.

However, C# is not as close to the metal as that. When we write C# we specify *intent* and let the compiler (and/or JITter) take care of the optimizations like tail calls, method inlining and the like. The presence of the C# `return` keyword does not necessarily imply or force some stack cleanup. Instead it indicates the programmer's *intent*.

If we allow you to leave out the "return" it makes the compiler's job of understanding your intent a lot more difficult. Was the programmer aware of the optimization that would happen and intends conceptually for the method to "return", or did he mean explicitly don't do anything with the result. C# assumes the latter.

Now, if you are concerned that the fact you can't leave out the return means that a tail call can't be performed, do not worry. The compiler and JITter take care of these sorts of optimizations automatically. They take your specified *intent* and *implement* it in the most optimized manner they can. And they almost always do a better job of deciding what and when to apply these sorts of optimizations than the programmer could.

Comment: The C# program behaves as expected. However, other languages (say, Python) don't require the return statement here. Python is pathological in its own way. C# is as well. Your answer makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: But the result with no return would surely be None and not a number?

Answer (score 1):

In short, a method in C# has to have a `return` on all code execution paths, you may not like it but it does. The same in Maths all functions have a result, that's what functions do.

Now on saying that, the result can be undefined, Infinity, 0, null, or in the case of C# with a return type of a non-nullable `int` it can be 0. Which makes perfect sense given the signature.

How about we pretend for a second we could just vanish the code execution at the point of your else. If the calling method is relying on a result (and they usually do) and even if the method ended the way you propose, then what is the caller going to think? well it needs to be able to deal with the absence of a value, or not.

If you really need to know that your else doesn't produce a value, make your signature `int?` (nullable ) and return `null`, so the caller knows what to do. if its just an absence of a number for sum then make it 0, no harm done

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can "get away with" not using a return is to throw an error instead. It doesn't make sense to do this in your situation.

You can also avoid using a return by not providing a code path (don't have an else clause, in this situation)

You have, however, done the right thing in that you've returned the result of recursively calling AddSquares2 in your else. If you don't do this, your code for AddSquares2 will never recurse and won't work (so you DID have to return something after all! Ahh).

Recursive methods must have a point inside themselves where they return without calling themselves (to stop recursion from going forever), and also a point where they call themselves (to keep recursion going for a while)

Probably an academic exercise but perhaps worth mentioning that recursion is a form of looping that (ab)uses the call stack into providing a looping construct. Recursive methods can (and should, imho) be done using normal loops

Comment: Depends on the language. I taught Common Lisp for years, and we used recursion almost everywhere we needed repetition. IMHO, recursion comes naturally and is easier to teach than iteration.